# Stuck with Cloudflare workers bulk origin proxy please

Tags: cdn, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers, webflow

I need some help with Cloudflare workers. I'm not a dev by any stretch of the imagination and use Webflow so no code, but I've got a Webflow project where I need to squeeze every ounce of speed out of the site and I'm trying it on my domain first.

I've got a Pro Cloudflare account set up for the project, but my problem is that Webflow keeps all the assets like `css`, fonts and most importantly images on `assets.website-files.com` (their CDN) and not my actual [domain](http://milkmoonstudio.com), so Cloudflare is not caching or applying any performance enhancements on the images, etc... as `assets.website-files.com` is not part of my domain as you can see from the screenshot:
[Dr.Falre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqWQA.jpg)

I contacted Cloudflare and they sent me this Cloudflare Workers script, but like I said, no code experience here, so would anyone here be able to help me out with this script from Cloudflare:

```
/**
 * An object with different URLs to fetch
 * @param {Object} ORIGINS
 */
const ORIGINS = {
  "starwarsapi.yourdomain.com": "swapi.dev",
  "google.yourdomain.com": "www.google.com",
}

async function handleRequest(request) {
  const url = new URL(request.url)
  // Check if incoming hostname is a key in the ORIGINS object
  if (url.hostname in ORIGINS) {
    const target = ORIGINS[url.hostname]
    url.hostname = target
    // If it is, proxy request to that third party origin
    return await fetch(url.toString(), request)
  }

  // Otherwise, process request as normal
  return await fetch(request)
}

addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})
```

Any help would be much appreciated.